# How to secure the login php-mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When users login in  my site, I have to connect to the database and validate their login. Now according to [this](http://w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp) site login process is `mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname);`
But if I use this method, any user who sees the source of my website will be able to see the database name, password. How do I secure it?

Comment: No one can see the source of your website unless they break into your server. And if you mean HTML source then that doesn't matter you can ignore that. PHP they wont see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I secure it?

How do you think users are able to see your sources? Just don't give your FTP/SSH account details to anyone ))